Is there some way to interrogate the state or exact control characters sent to a PTY or TTY in MacOS to determine why it is frozen?
This is another approach to my earlier question.
The high-level problem is that a curses based program is causing the pty to freeze on certain machines and not others. The PTY neither passes input to the process nor prints output from the process, so I'm guessing that something output by the curses program is giving it indigestion.
Is there a way to interrogate the state of the pty from another terminal to determine whether there is some kind of IO suspension happening?
Is there a way get the exact control characters sent to a PTY since its creation?
